# USB C keeps disconnecting

Tags: usb, usb-drive, usb-c

I'm using an Acer E 15 laptop with Ubuntu 18.

I get my self **Roline USB3.1 Hub 4-port** what connect to **USB Type C**.
When I plug USB in any of that 4 ports I got disconnecting in short random time. Like the 6-7 time in one minute. And if I leave connected on a whole hub gets hot.

- Didn't try to connect to other PC/Laptop with Windows or some other OS
- And I can't finish any task with that USB.
- All others USB works and all ok.

Newer have this kind of problems. Any words of wisdom?

Comment: Heat... disconnections... sounds like a dodgy lead, perhaps with a short circuit.  Did you get a proper branded lead or a cheap one?  Perhaps do a continuity test on it, if you can.

Comment: I'll try soon test the hub on other pc.
Hub cost 50$. Is kinda not a cheap one. Not sure is up to hub or to laptop USB C